# Extracting nested JSON object name is undefined?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2, jspdf

done this a hundred times and sometimes I don't understand why it does not work, here is the data:

```
"data": [
        {
            "id": "61c5b633-2bf4-4ed9-bdbb-39daf18e354c",
            "name": "Donegal Bay",
            "geom": null,
            "area": null,
            "aquacultureType": "Shellfish",
            "cultureType": "Extensive",
            "farmingMethod": [
                "trestle-bag"
            ],
            "ownershipType": "owned",
            "image": "",
            "createdAt": "2021-07-05T10:39:07.482Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-07-05T10:39:07.482Z",
            "bayId": "b6d939fb-6eab-46ff-97d8-b004b7c6e62f",
            "bay": {
                "id": "b6d939fb-6eab-46ff-97d8-b004b7c6e62f",
                "state": "Donegal Bay"
            }
        },
```

I need to get the bay -> state ( Donegal Bay )

The problem is its telling me its undefined, I tried data.bay.state, data.bay is also empty. Not sure why, it happened to me before not sure why this happens, any help is really appreciated thank you!

Trying to put the bay name or 'state' into a

```
    doc.setFontSize(15)
    doc.text('Bay: ' + farmData.bay.state, 20,60)
```

Using jsPDF

when I do data.name it works perfectly.

Comment: Don't you see the `[`? That means it's an array. Which means you need an array index.

Comment: `farmData[0].bay.state`

Comment: Are `data` and `farmData` the same thing?

Comment: I can't see any way that `data.name` could be working if `data.bay` doesn't.

Comment: @MichalKubiak Can you share a little bit more code? What you posted is incomplete and syntactically incorrect. Most likely it will be very easy for us to help you, if you would just post a little bit more code.

Comment: Sorry lads  yea farmData and data is the same thing that's why I'm confused, I tried farmData[0].bay.state does not work either, when I delete that line of code it then works or rather lets me download the pdf via button so something wrong there not sure,

Comment: let farmData = (await farmService.loadFarmMetaData()).data.data;
      let licenses = (await farmService.loadFarmLicenses()).data.data;
      let company = (await farmService.loadCompanyData(licenses[0].companyId))

Comment: Those three work, when I then do let bay = farmData[0].bay.state it does not work can't really share any more code, Ill figure a way around it I have before its happened before thought there was some weird javascript thing that happens in these cases but clearly not, thanks guys!

Comment: Log farm data, perhaps its an empty array, null, or undefined.